# Meaning of 全数 when talking about frequency

Tags: translation, meaning, words, adverbs, time

In an article about quality control, I found the following expression:

> 検査頻度: **全数**

I read in the dictionary that 全数 means "total, complete". Since we are talking about frequency, I thought it could be interpreted as "every time" in this case, but it doesn't make sense to me. Does it simply mean "often" or "high"?

I don't know if this can be of any help, but later in the article it is also used inside a sentence (UT and PT are types of inspections):

> No.１側構体の車外側は**全数**全線のＵＴ，ＰＴを行うことを原則とする．

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 3):

全数 clearly means "all", and 全数検査 means everything is subject to inspection. The opposing concept is 標本調査/検査 ("sampling survey"), where only a random subset of the target will be inspected. "Every time" may also be a valid translation depending on what they are checking.